# Slide show with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, transition

I wrote this line of code to animate the pictures on my webpage:

```
var SlideShow = function (container) {
    this.images = [];
    this.curImage = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < container.childElementCount; i++) {
        this.images.push(container.children[i]);
        this.images[i].style.display = "none";
        }

var nextSlide = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
        this.images[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        this.images[this.curImage].style.display = "block";
        this.curImage++;

        if (this.curImage >= this.images.length) {
            this.curImage = 0;
        }
        window.setTimeout(nextSlide.bind(this), 3000);
    };

    nextSlide.call(this);
};

SlideShow(document.getElementById("testslide"));
```

The slide show works, pictures change but the style is boring. I want it to either slide in from the right to the left or fade in or something similar, any style at all other than just changing. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Don't hide images using JS. when the document loads all images will be visible for a fraction of time - before JS kicks in. Use CSS.

Comment: Use CSS transition to make it better. And add/remove a class to tell the browser which is the front one.

Comment: Thank you Roko, I will give a try.